# selecting a record from a table based on column value of another table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I know forming this query is trivial, but I am not able frame the exact query. Based on what I have read so far, the solution may include joining two tables. Here is the problem :

```
TABLE_ONE {S_NO, DK_NO, FRM , DATE}

TABLE_TWO {S_NO, DK_NO , TO}
```

I want to select a record from `TABLE_ONE` based on an input value of `DK_NO` and value checked for TO field of `TABLE_TWO` or FRM field of `TABLE_ONE`

unsuccessful trials so far:

1)

```
$sql = "select * from TABLE_ONE where DK_NO like '%".$dkno."%' and (FRM='".$department."' or  (TABLE_TWO.DK_NO like '%".$dakno."%' and TABLE_TWO.TO='".$department."'))";
```

2)

```
$sql = "select * from TABLE_ONE where DK_NO like '%".$dkno."%' and (FRM='".$department."' or   TABLE_TWO.TO='".$department."')";
```

Comment: Search JOINs and what they do

Comment: What is the relationship between the 2 tables? Is `S_NO` the same value in both?

Comment: no DK_NO of TABLE_TWO is a foreign key

Comment: So `TABLE_ONE.S_NO = TABLE_TWO.DK_NO`?

Comment: actually DK_NO in TABLE_ONE IS UNIQUE, while DK_NO in TABLE_TWO has a foreign key constraint, so TABLE_ONE.DK_NO = TABLE_TWO.DK_NO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recommended reading: [JOIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html).

Using inner join:

```
"select t1.* 
from table_one t1 inner join table_two t2 on t1.dk_no = t2.dk_no
where (t1.frm = '". $department. "' or t2.to = '".$department. "') 
    and t1.dk_no like '%" . $dkno . "%'";
```

Comment: @AkashGupta, You're welcome.  I updated my answer to reflect the appropriate join columns based on your comments in the question.

Answer (score 1):

You need to join your tables. Try something like -

```
SELECT
    T1.*
FROM
    TABLE_ONE T1
JOIN
    TABLE_TWO T2
ON
    T1.DK_NO = T2.DK_NO
WHERE
    T1.DK_NO like '%".$dkno."%' 
AND
    (T1.FRM='".$department."' OR TABLE_TWO.TO='".$department."')
```